# how to give a truth value for the following formula

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am trying give a structure that makes that makes the formula T and a structure that makes the formula F for the following formula

```
∀X•(p(X) ⇔ q(X)) ∧ ∃Y•(p(Y) ∨ q(X))
```

so I thought for the T value I could use the domain of all humans say that p is Love and q is happy. So the meaning would be if X is in love means the X is happy and vice versa but I am not sure what do for Y.

Comment: @AndréNicolas sorry about that, I have no amended it.

Comment: The formula has a free occurrence of $X$, in the second $q(X)$. Is that intended?

Comment: @AndréNicolas yes it is

Comment: For example, to make it false, use the structure that has a single element $a$, and assign the value false to both $p(a)$ and $q(a)$.

Comment: sorry I am slightly confused, what about the value of Y

Comment: There is no value of $Y$, it is quantified, and for the model I mention above $\exists Y (p(Y)\lor q(X))$ is false for every value of $X$. The bi-implication at the beginning is true, but the whole formula is false, because of the $\land$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula has a free occurrence of the variable symbol $X$. For clarity, we replace the bound occurrences of $X$ by $Z$, so we are looking at the formula 
$$\forall z(p(Z)\iff q(Z))\land \exists Y(p(Y)\lor q(X)).\tag{1}$$

Some would not assign a truth value to formulas with free occurrences of variable symbols. Some would assign to such a formula the same truth value as to the sentence obtained by universally quantifying all free occurrences of variable symbols. We take the latter point of view.

To make the formula (1) true, we can use the following interpretation. Let the universe of discourse consist of a single object $a$, and let $p(a)$ and $q(a)$ be true.

To make the formula (1) false, we can let the universe consist of a single object $a$, and let $p(a)$ and $q(a)$ be false. The $\forall Z(p(Z)\iff q(Z))$ part of (1) is true, but the $\exists Y(p(Y)\lor q(X))$ part is false, so their conjunction (1) is false.